# INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY when subscribing role members to a record

Tags: apex, trigger, profile, chatter-feed-tracking

I created a trigger that on a record creation (Custom sObject), subscribes all the createdBy role members to the record.

This code seems to work just fine when executed by a sys admin, but it throws the following error for a user with Chatter Only profile.

> Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error:
>   INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access
>   rights on cross-reference id: []

What I'm missing here ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was me! I forgot to remove the "With sharing" keyword from the class definition. 
My bad!

Answer (score 0):

Chatter Only profile might not be having sufficient permissions like  create,read,update and delete permissions. once check those permissions.

Comment: Actually he has the right to do so. I tried with hardcoded Ids in a list of EntitySubscription and they were inserted correctly .