# Insufficient access rights on cross reference id on Entity Subscription

Tags: apex, controller, customer-portal

I have some code which creates an EntitySubscription so the owner of an Account auto-follows any case created. The case is created in a controller in Portal. The Community User has Read/Create/Edit on the Case object.

```
 follow=new List<EntitySubscription>();
 System.debug('Network Id ' + Network.getNetworkId());
 EntitySubscription followCaseByOwner = new EntitySubscription(
       parentId = caseRec.Id,
       subscriberId = currentUser.Id,
       networkId = setNetworkId
 );
 follow.add(followCaseByOwner);

 EntitySubscription followCaseByPSA = new EntitySubscription(
       parentId = caseRec.Id,
       subscriberId = ownerId
 );
 follow.add(followCaseByPSA);
 insert follow;
```

Is there something special with the subscriberId? I know that by default the NetworkId is set to internal, which I want.

Also I get the error when running the unit test.

**UPDATE**

By setting the keyword 'without sharing' on the class the test passes. But why is it working in UI, it creates a record in the EntitySubscription but it's not working when I call the same method in the unit test.

Any suggestions?

Comment: These errors can be seen when an entry already exists for the parentId, and subscriberId combination. The way to stop these is to check before insertion and 'don't insert' if one already exists; or delete the existing one and insert the new one. Do you think this is the case in your scenario?

Comment: I am inserting two EntitySubsciptions, but what I forgot to mention is that it's working when testing it in the portal, but getting the error when running a unit test

Comment: In your unit test, when you add the case SFDC will be creating a EntitySubscription behind the scenes and so you may have a duplicate when inserting your 2nd EntitySubscription as it'll be a duplicate to the SFDC created one.

Comment: I'm calling the method that saves a case in the controller, the method is responsible for the creation. I'm not creating the case in the unit test. Also I tried to select all the records from the EntitySubscription object after the insertion of the Case but before the code that creates the EntitySubscription and it doesn't return anything. Can you point me to some documentation where it says that SFDC creates by default an EntitySubscription?

Comment: Apologies I may have got that automated bit wrong - thinking of something else. btw - after looking some people have stated a problem with 'with sharing' on classes that access EntitySubscription; perhaps that is the probem? (http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/32627/insufficient-access-on-cross-reference-entity-when-subscribing-role-members-to-a)

Comment: If I set the keyword 'without sharing' on the class, the test passes. Now the question is: are there any sharing constraints set by Salesforce? or do I have to look for any custom sharing rules? And why it's working in the UI